# cannot toggle checkbox using Redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, action, dispatch

I wanna check in my completed button but by dispatching the action from my todoSlice.js to my TodoItem.js. However, when i click on the checkbox, nothing happens tho there's no mistake in the console, nothing updated in the redux console either...please help me find out what's wrong! Thank you so much!

todoSlice.js:

```
import {
    createSlice
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name: "todo",
    initialState: [{
        id: 1,
        title: "todo1",
        completed: false,
    }, {
        id: 2,
        title: "todo2",
        completed: false,
    }, {
        id: 3,
        title: "todo3",
        completed: true,
    }, ],
    reducers: {
        addTodo: (state, action) => {
            const newTodo = {
                id: Date.now(),
                title: action.payload.title,
                completed: false,
            };
            state.push(newTodo);
        },
        toggleComplete: (state, action) => {
            const index = state.findIndex(
                (todo) => todo.id === action.payload.id
            )
            state[index].completed = action.payload.completed
        }
    },
});
export const {
    addTodo,
    toggleComplete,
} = todoSlice.actions;
export default todoSlice.reducer;
```

TodoItem.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { toggleComplete } from "../redux/todoSlice";

const TodoItem = ({ id, title, completed }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCompleteClick = () => {
    console.log("helllo");
    dispatch(
      toggleComplete({
        id: id,
        completed: !completed,
      })
    );
  };
  return (
    <li className={`list-group-item ${completed && "list-group-item-success"}`}>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span className="d-flex align-items-center">
          <input type="checkbox" className="mr-3" checked={completed} /> {title}{" "}
        </span>{" "}
        <button className="btn btn-danger"> Delete </button>{" "}
      </div>{" "}
    </li>
  );
};

export default TodoItem;
```

Comment: `handleCompleteClick` is declared but it's not used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add onClick handler to button like this:

```
<button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={handleCompleteClick}> Delete </button>{" "}
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working...

Comment: In this case console is empty? Or you saw "helllo"? If yes, then show how you're create and add store to App.

Comment: i don't see "hello"

Comment: what do you mean "then show how you're create and add store to App"?